# How to change http://localhost:8000/ to other domain name in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel-4

I have recently started working on Laravel 4.2 (with Ubuntu OS). 
Can some one help me on how can I replace/alias http://localhost:8000/ with something like dev.laravel.com. Thanks in advance!

/etc/hosts

```html
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 dev.training.com
127.0.0.1 dev.lessons.com
127.0.0.1 dev.pingpong.com
127.0.0.1 dev.wireframe.com
127.0.0.1 dev.laravel.com
127.0.0.1 dev.newapp.com
127.0.1.1 srturaka-pc

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Virtual Hosts Settings

```html
<VirtualHost dev.laravel.com:8000>
  ServerName dev.laravel.com
  ServerAlias www.dev.laravel.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dev.laravel.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You have apache or nginx?

Comment: You must edit your web server configuration to create a virtual host. If you are using Apache, you should read this: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html Besides, you'll also need to edit your local DNS configuration. If you are using Linux, you'll have to edit /etc/hosts to add the virtual host domain to it, pointing to your localhost (127.0.0.1).

Comment: @Iwan I am using apache2.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida Thanks for the information. I have followed those instructions and managed to replace domain name to dev.laravel.com:8000 from localhost:8000. But still I am looking for an option if I can alias it to dev.laravel.com without 8000. Sorry if it is a silly question I am new to this virtual host thing. :) I have pasted my new VH settings in my question. You may have a look.

Comment: Not silly at all. I only gave you this information because I faced this very same moment myself. Let me tell you one possible solution to this problem of the port 8000. You may create a rule in your firewall. A rule to catch all TCP packets in your loopback interface going to port 8000 and send them to port 80, which is the default port to your HTTP server. I think this will do what you want.